# Moving wp-config.php outside root folder where we have multiple wordpress websites for enhanced security

Tags: security, wp-config

I have moved wp-config.php but my file structure is as given below:

```
public_html
--abccom
--applecom
--wp-config.php
```

**abcom** and **applecom** folder has  wordpress websites both
As advised, I have moved **wp-config.php** outside **abccom** for security, but now when I need to do the same for applecom, how can I achieve it?

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-wordpress-wp-configphp--cms-27737

Answer (score 1):

Move wp-config.php to its new location somewhere above "public_html" and add a new "skeleton" wp-config.ph in the WordPress directory e.g.

```
<?php
include('/dir_above_public_html/priv-applecom/wp-config.php');
?>
```

The wp-config.php script is included by other WordPress files. So to include this from a non default location we can simply 1. move our "real" wp-config from the Wordpress directory to where we want it located. 2. create a new wp-config in the Wordpress directory that does its own includes of the "real" wp-config script.

The benefits of having this file above `public_html/web-root` are hotly debated. I am in the camp that wants to avoid having scripts with authentication keys, salts & DB "credentials" in a directory that might be  accessed via HTTP(S).

There are no real benefits in moving wp-config to another accessible dir (this may be the case for "abccom" where you have moved it to a dir "public_html" which usually indicates it is yes "public".